# Objective-C/Cocoa windowScriptObject commands not working from loaded page

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I am trying to get a 'windowScriptObject' working, this is my Objective-C code below:

```
- (void)consoleLog:(NSString *)aMessage {
    NSLog(@"JSLog: %@", aMessage); }

+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector {
    if (aSelector == @selector(consoleLog:)) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES; }

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {

    NSLog(@"Did finnish load...");
    scriptObject = [sender windowScriptObject];

    //obviously, this returns undefined
    NSLog(@"Object: %@",[scriptObject evaluateWebScript:@"MyApp"]);

    //set the value of MyApp
    [scriptObject setValue:self forKey:@"MyApp"];

    //this now returns the value
    NSLog(@"Object: %@",[scriptObject evaluateWebScript:@"MyApp"]);




    //this command now works from here
    [scriptObject evaluateWebScript:@"MyApp.consoleLog_('Test');"]; 
}
```

The above code works when I inject JavaScript (*evaluateWebScript*)

This sis what the console out put is:

```
2012-12-06 08:03:05.605 BetterDesktop[8669:303] Did finnish load...
2012-12-06 08:03:05.605 BetterDesktop[8669:303] Object: undefined
2012-12-06 08:03:05.606 BetterDesktop[8669:303] Object: <WidgetsDelegate: 0x10133de60>
2012-12-06 08:03:05.607 BetterDesktop[8669:303] JSLog: Test
```

The command works, however when I use a page it doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof(MyApp) != "undefined"){
document.write('<br/><h1>hi</h1>');
MyApp.consoleLog_('Test from HTML');
}
else{

document.write('<br/><h1>Not Defined</h1>');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It believes that 'MyApp' is undefined, any suggestions?

(By the way, the WebView is not connected to this class, it is just the delegate)

Comment: Ok, so I've found that if I run the code in an 'onclick' method it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should inject your objects in to the WebView from within the `-webView:didClearWindowObject:forFrame:` `WebFrameLoadDelegate` method rather than within `-webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:`. The `window` object is not guaranteed to have been correctly initialized until `didClearWindowObject` is called.